# Delete Records from a database

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, database, crud

I am trying to delete set of records under my ASP.NET Application - API Controller. Here is my code from API Controller:

```
    public JsonResult Delete([FromBody]ICollection<ShoppingItemViewModel> vm)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                var items = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<ShoppingItem>>(vm);
                _repository.DeleteValues(items, User.Identity.Name);
                return Json(null);
            }
            catch (Exception Ex)
            {
                Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
                return Json(null);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
            return Json(null);
        }
    }
```

And here is my AngularJS Controller part taking care of this:

```
    $scope.RemoveItems = function () {
        $scope.isBusy = true;

        $http.delete("/api/items", $scope.items)
            .then(function (response) {
                if (response.statusText == "OK" && response.status == 200) {
                    //passed
                    for (var i = $scope.items.length - 1; i > -1; i--) {
                        if ($scope.items[i].toRemove == true) {
                            $scope.items.splice(i, 1);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }, function (err) {
                $scope.errorMessage = "Error occured: " + err;
            }).finally(function () {
                $scope.isBusy = false;
            });

    }
```

For unknown reason, this works like a charm in my `POST` method but not in the `Delete` Method. I believe that the problem might be caused by the fact, that DELETE method only accepts `Integer` **ID**?

If that is the case, what is the *correct* way how to delete multiple items with one call?

Comment: What does your `DeleteValues` do?

Comment: Makes a call to a repository, which removes specific items from the database. The problem however is, that I cannot pass my `ICollection` to my API Controller. When I debug my solution, the value that is being passed to my controller is always null